# E-Forms using standard edition

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

We have SharePoint 2010 Standard Edition license and we are covered in Enterprise Agreement but we are in need of E-Forms and put it on our portal using workflows also. I've heard info path services only available in Enterprise license.

Is there any way we can develop E-Forms and can use it in Standard Edition? Plz guide.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoPath forms services are only available with the enterprise edition. That means that you cannot use Info Path forms as server hosted and browser rendered solution. If you cannot upgrade your SP license you will have to go for custom ASP forms, which might be some more effort but therefore more flexible.

Here some links that may help you get started:

- http://blogs.mosshosting.com/archive/2009/02/13/electronic-forms-infopath-or-asp-net.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828810/en-us
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ASPNET_to_Sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Alex thanks for your reply. I would love that because I have been developing web applications using asp.net C# (3.5 framework)..Can you guide me in the direction or provide links to get started with your suggestion regarding custom ASP forms?

Comment: There are tons of information out there. Since I don't know what you already now, I will give you some resources that were helpful to me. I updated the answer with the links.